# Measuring process loading time

Tags: windows, testing, dll, process

I am currently creating a DLL that patches the process memory when it gets called by DLL_THREAD_ATTACH (or DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH for the main thread). Now I wanted to measure the performance of my DLL by comparing the time it takes for a process to load without my dll attached to it, to when it is attached.

However, I have now clue how to measure this "startup" time, so the time from creating the process to reaching the entry point of the process.

(This is for Windows processes).

Comment: Can't you simply measure time your DLL needs to do its job? DLL loading time is probably negligible (unless user will start that process 1000 times per second)...

Comment: You may create another (console) application and launch the process from it. Measure the time between CreateProcess and WaitForInputIdle.